# Intel XDK hide android navigation bar

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I need to hide the **navigation bar** on android 5.0+. I need information about the **intel XDK** for change flag or add flag.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to look into the UI framework that you are using alongside the XDK. This is usually where the calls to hide the bar need to be made.
For example, using ionic, this seems to be the approach (we tried it on our app, and it works)

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});
```

see:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/statusbar-hide-ruins-the-layout/1790/4

Comment: You talk about Status Bar (battery, notify) and I need to hide the navigation bar.

Comment: I love ionic ! Thank you ! Because : i can choose my browser !